# Managing "cookies" with Store.js

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm using localStorage to create a type of cookie inside my page, to track the activity of a user within my website. To achieve retro-compatibility, I'm using the Store.js library.

The workflow that I'm trying to achieve is the following: If an entry with the name 'cookieName' exists, update it to contain another entry in the pagesVisited. If no entry exists, create a new entry, and add the current page to the visited pages.

The way to implement the edit that I could get to work, was to get the current data of the entry, delete it, and create a new one with the updated values. I'm guessing that maybe if the  entry gets big, this might slow the page down a bit.

1. Is this a concern? Can it slow my page down a lot?
2. Is there a better way to do an edit with Store.js?

Here is the link to the repo of the library [Store.Js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/)

Just to clarify, I'm using localstorage instead of cookies because I don't need any client-server comunication (or not very oftern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont have to remove an existing item and write a new one if they have same key. the store.js-set-method internally uses "localStorage.setItem" which just overrides the current value.

other than that, i dont see any other way to do it, if you want to store that data on the client.

but keep in mind, that the **total** storagesize for a domain is limited (see this wikipedia-article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage), and store.js doesnt seem to catch any exceptions when setting a value, so you probably should do that by yourself (catch the quota exceeded exception), and provide a fallback in your catch-block (there seems to be some browsers where facebook is spamming the localstorage). if you want you can possible clear the total localStorage (store.js provides the clear-method) and try to save your value again

Comment: Ty for that. I setted with the same key, and it worked like a charm ;) And I'll keep in mind the max exception. Thanks a lot